# Nuget Error 'ns:package/ns:metadata/ns:id' in the XML file was not found

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package

When running nuget in my build to create a package I get:

'ns:package/ns:metadata/ns:id' in the XML file was not found

[image]

my NSPec which was generated from

> nuget spec [Application Name]

which returns

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>E.Commerce.Site</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>administrator</authors>
    <owners>administrator</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>description</description>
    <releaseNotes>release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
    <tags>ESITE</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlns is required to run through this tool and is not included when nuget.exe generates the NSPEC

notice:
 **xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd>
  <metadata>
    <id>E.Commerce.Site</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>administrator</authors>
    <owners>administrator</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>description</description>
    <releaseNotes>release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
    <tags>ESITE</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```